# Format using 4 spaces instead of 2 in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, tabs, settings, indentation, space

When I open a file in VS Code and press `Alt + Shift + F`, the opened file gets formatted. The 2 spaces indentation gets used in html, js, etc. even though my configurations specify 4 spaces. How could I fix it?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can refer the same issue in Visual Studio. Relevent changes for each type of file extesion exist in different section with the same heading. For example C# and JavaScript/TypeScript has the same settings. So make sure you are modifying correct one.

[image]